# AJAX and Node.js with dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

The situation I am in is akin to this question; If you were a developer on some social media website, and you had to implement the ability for a user to like/favorite something without reloading the page how would you do it. I am building an app using Node.js, Express, and Handlebars. I've come to a point where I do not know which path to take. Here is where I'm at:

```
      <form method="POST" action="/favoriteCreator">
              <input type="submit" name="{{this.id}}" value="{{this.fname}} {{this.lname}}">
            </form>
```

Basically what is happening is that for every person, a form is created with a button of type submit. Hypothetically speaking then, there could be a million forms with a million buttons. At this point what I am trying to do is make it so that when the form is submitted, it will add a creator as a "favorite creator" to my database. I decided to make the forms simply due to the possibility that the user could have JS disabled. I don't want it to reload the page when a user favorites someone, so I am trying to use AJAX.

```
<script>

$('#theform').on('submit', function (event) {
//alert('Hi');
event.preventDefault();
var data = {
  creatorname: this.name,
};

$.ajax({
  url: '/something',
  data: data,
  method: 'POST'
})
```

I'm having a problem where for one thing, the forms have no id or name. I know that forms are not allowed to have the same ID, but if I made them the same name I feel like bad things could happen. Also, even if I managed to get past that aspect, I don't know how I would get the 'name={{this.id}}' attribute. Right now i have it as this.name, but I don't think that would work to be perfectly honest. As you can see, its really one thing after the other for me with this. I've never really used AJAX before, so this whole thing is pretty foreign to me. I don't want to end up finding some barely working method, and then having to come back and redo everything later, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Not clear question.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm having a problem where for one thing, the forms have no id or name.

   - The forms can have the same class name. and you can pass the class name as a parameter.
2. I know that forms are not allowed to have the same ID, but if I made them the same name I feel like bad things could happen. Also, even if I managed to get past that aspect, I don't know how I would get the 'name={{this.id}}' attribute.

   - You can try using {{this.name}}
3. Right now I have it as this.name, but I don't think that would work to be perfectly honest.

   - Why do you think It would not work? It is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are bad for doing ajax operations. just regular buttons would do, but what you have done to stop propagation is a good way.

- To solve your id scenario, do it via a class
- To solve your data scenario use [html data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)

try this

```js
$('.formClass').on('submit', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  var data = {
    user: $(event.target[0]).data('user')
  }

  $('.optput').text(data.user)

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users',
    data: data,
    method: 'POST'
  }).done(function(d) {
    console.log(d)
  })

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
}

.forms {
  display: flex
}

.formClass {
  margin: 10px;
}

#banner-message {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='forms'>
  <form class='formClass' name='testform'>
    <input type='submit' data-user='user1' value='click me' class='button' />
  </form>
  <form class='formClass' name='testform'>
    <input type='submit' data-user='user2' value='click me' class='button' />
  </form>
  <form class='formClass' name='testform'>
    <input type='submit' data-user='user3' value='click me' class='button' />
  </form>
  <label id='banner-message' class='optput'></label>
</div>
```